# Tensorflow running out of GPU memory between two models

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Tensorflow is running out of memory between running two models. The batch size doesn't seem to make a difference. I've tried the clear session command seen in my example code below as well as del model and gc.collect, and tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True).

A single model runs fine it's only after 1 or 2 where the memory runs out.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X_train = np.random.rand(1000000, 768)
X_test = np.random.rand(100, 768)
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 4, size=1000000)
y_test = np.random.randint(0, 4, size=100)

print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=5, dtype='float32')
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=5, dtype='float32')

for i in range(10):
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(768,), name='input'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(768, activation='gelu', name='dense1'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(96, activation='gelu', name='dense2'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.05),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='output')
    ])

    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)  # 0.0005 was best so far.
    es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10)

    model.compile(optimizer=opt,
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[es], batch_size=0)
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)
```

Here's the beginning out the output:

```
2022-09-01 18:26:08.068402: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6010 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:2b:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
2022-09-01 18:26:09.076943: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 2764800000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
28125/28125 [==============================] - 55s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3878 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2506 - val_loss: 1.3863 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.2521
4/4 - 0s - loss: 1.3873 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2400 - 84ms/epoch - 21ms/step
2022-09-01 18:27:05.890074: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 2764800000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
28106/28125 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3874 - categorical_accuracy: 0.24992022-09-01 18:28:07.971774: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:479] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.91MiB (rounded to 2000128)requested by op _EagerConst
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation.
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
```

Thanks for any help

edit: This is using tensorflow 2.9.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: How much RAM do you have in this system?

Comment: 32gb RAM, my gpu has 8gb. I believe from my research before this that this error is gpu memory specific.

Comment: Although you've specified a `batch_size`, you're still loading the entire data into memory at once (which is what eventually causes the memory to fill up). What you need to do is to create data generators that can feed the models with `batch_size` number of samples each time. Have you looked into this Keras example: https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/structured_data_classification_from_scratch/